# Selecting text and show meaning as pop up in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to make a book app, and to define or translate every sentence in it. The thing I want to know is how to make the translation appear as a pop up text for every single textview I click on it. For example "How are you" is in a textview and after I click and hold on  it a pop up menu appear with the translate option.

Comment: Use [toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) to create pop-up.

Comment: @DroidDev would you please see this?

Comment: @lostsock I'm not allowed to do so, I'm new here and still dont have the required reputation to post new Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depend on how you want it to look. You could a [toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html), a context menu or a dialog.