# Why my application working normally on the emulator but stops on my device?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, listview

I have finished my app and its working normally and just fine with eclipse emulator, but when I install it on my device it says "Unfortunately it has stopped ", knowing that I have tried other projects on the device and worked, so why this one wont? someone help if you please.

Thanks.

Comment: are you able to open the database in your app?
show the code at which you are opening it. Have you tried to implement a cursoradapter to display whatever it is that is inside?

Comment: @DanielBo yes I did and its working but what about the empty rows?

Comment: seems like your sql statement pulls everything from the database. You need to fetch only those, rthat actually do have a telephonenumber

Comment: @DanielBo,this is my cursor that my listview takes it as adapter, 
public Cursor getAllRecord() {
  
return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Student", null); } 
but when I specify a column like
 ("SELECT c_phone FROM Student", null); it does not work, so how should I do it?

Comment: @DanielBo can you help with this new question?

Comment: define, it does not work. it crashes? - if so add logcat to original post. edit it!

Comment: on the emulator it runs normally so there is no crashes to report, but when I try it on my tablet it did not open "Unfortunately it has stopped ", and my tablet is lenovo which I couldn't found any usb diver on there site that developer.android mentioned, so I cant see the logcat on the tab

Comment: @DanielBo forget this one, the other question is more important for me and I appreciate your help so would you please see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611755/how-to-make-bind-view-display-column-mathes-the-id-taken-from-onitemclick) I couldnt solve it yet which made me to create an adapter class for each column I wanted to display in each 3 different activities, while I know there is a way to reduce it to only one, but I'm still searching. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because I have pushed my db through File explorer and not creating it with this code [here](http://sdrv.ms/N857Wn). That's why it will only work with the emulator and not the device.